# filling user read input automatically in shell

Tags: bash, shell

there is a shell library that I am not in control of that does not accept user parameters. When I run script.sh, it asks me to input a parameter. I was wondering if there is a way to assign those parameters automatically in another file.

More details:
I am guessing the shell library that I am not able to edit or view source code has something like this:

```
echo "Do that? [Y,n]"
read DO_THAT
if [ "$DO_THAT" = "y" ]; then
  do_that
fi
```

What I want is to run a file that will assign 'y' to the read parameter 'DO_THAT'.. but I do not know what the read parameter is called.

current command that I tried is:

```
./script.sh
echo "y"
```

or

```
./script.sh y
```

both did not work.

What happens if I run ./script.sh directly:

```
-bash-4.2$ ./script.sh
-bash-4.2$ Do that? [Y,n]:
```

I input y then click enter. What is the equivalent to user inputting a y then clicking enter in bash code in my scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of pressing Enter is a newline character. There are a few ways you could send a `y` followed by a newline:

In this case you can use [`yes`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/yes) in a pipeline. `yes` simply keeps printing a string (by default `y`) followed by a newline until it's killed. Using your example:

```
$ yes | ./script.sh
./script.sh: line 3: do_that: command not found
```

Or you could use a [here-string](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings):

```
./script.sh <<< y
```

Or simply `echo` in a pipeline:

```
echo y | ./script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to have scripts take the standard input from a file is input redirection. With `some_file.params` containing 'y', Your example script will work as expected with

```
./script.sh < somefile.params
```

Note this is sensitive to any character - in particular, you need new lines to "press enter", and if you have two you may input an empty string to some of your reads.